# Docker image not able to stay alive in a Jenkins Kubernetes build pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, argocd

We want to deploy using ArgoCD from our Jenkinsfile (which is slightly not how this is intended to be done but close enough), and after done some experiments want to try using the official container with the CLI, so we have added this snippet to our our pipeline kubernetes yaml:

```
  - name: argocdcli
    image: argoproj/argocli
    command:
    - argo
    args: 
    - version
    tty: true
```

Unfortunately the usual way to keep these containers alive is to invoke `cat` in the container, which isn't there, so it fails miserably.  Actually the *only* command in there is the "argo" command which doesn't have a way to sleep infinitely.  (We are going to report this upstream so it will be fixed, but while we wait for that....)

My question therefore is, is there a way to indicate to Kubernetes that we *know* that this pod cannot keep itself up on its own, and therefore not tear it down immediately?

Comment: Why does it need to stay running after it’s done?

Comment: @coderanger Apparently that is the way that the Jenkins kubernetes plugin runs containers in its agents. There is a "sleep forever"-command that keeps the pod up, and then Jenkins invokes the actual commands in the pod as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible since as you stated, `argo` is the only command available on this image.

It can be confirmed [here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/Dockerfile#L97-L102):

```
####################################################################################################
# argocli
####################################################################################################
FROM scratch as argocli
COPY --from=argo-build /go/src/github.com/argoproj/argo/dist/argo-linux-amd64 /bin/argo
ENTRYPOINT [ "argo" ]
```

As we can see on this output, running argo is all this container is doing:

```
$ kubectl run -i --tty --image argoproj/argocli argoproj1 --restart=Never 
argo is the command line interface to Argo

Usage:
  argo [flags]
  argo [command]
...
```

You can optionally create you own image based on that and include sleep, so it'll be possible to keep it running as in this example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox:1.28
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.  I had to dump the filesystem from the pod to investigate (this definitively needs better tooling).

Comment: But the question was if there was a way to tell kubernetes to ignore that and keep the pod up anyway?

Comment: You change the command to run argo in the background, then use `cat` or `sleep` to keep the main process running

Comment: There is no way to do that on Kubernetes. There is no "hold", "wait", "sleep" or any other option you can use on kubernetes side to keep this pod up after finishing it's task.